# Java enum constructor call in foreach loop

Tags: java, enums

Can somebody help me understand why the output of the following code, in java:

```
public class Main {

    public static int position1, position2;

    private enum Direction{
        North(1,1),
        South(-1,-1),
        West(-1,0),
        East(1,0);

        Direction(int i, int j){
            position1=i;
            position2=j;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){       

        for(Direction d: Direction.values()){
            System.out.println(d + " has coordinates (" + position1 + "," + position2 + ")");
        }

    }  
}
```

The output is:

```
North has coordinates (1,0)
South has coordinates (1,0)
West has coordinates (1,0)
East has coordinates (1,0)
```

This is, the constructor is called always with the arguments of the element East. Why is this happening? I can't seem to find this explained anywhere.

Comment: I can't believe you get `(1,22)`, but more `(1,0)`. But what do you think the keyword `static` means in `public static int position1, position2;`?

Comment: Your fields are `static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position1` and `position2` are `static`, and on the `Main` class. That means they're global there's just one version of each field for anyone who uses `Main`. What you want are *instance* fields on *`Direction`*. There's more info at the [Java tutorial on member fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

```
private enum Direction {
    public int position1, position2;
    ...
}
```

You need to remove the `static` keyword, so that each `Direction` has its own `position1` and `position2` values. You may also want to mark them as `final`, which means they can only be set once (that's a good general practice, for various reasons: makes it easier to reason about state, catches bugs like this where you accidentally overwrite values, makes for thread-safe code, etc).

When you access them, you need to specify which instance you want to get the position for:

```
d.position1
```

(instead of just `position1`)

The reason this happens is that when you first use the `Direction` enum, the JVM loads each of its four values. To do that, each value runs its constructor. For instance, when it loads `North` it runs `North(1, 1)` which sets `position1 = 1; position2 = 1`. Then, when it loads `South` it runs `South(-1, -1)`, which then sets `position1 = -1; position2 = -1;`. Since there's only one version of each field (that's what `static` does), this `South` constructor simply overwrites the values that the `North` constructor wrote. The end result is that you'll get the `position1` and `position2` values for whichever constructor ran last. Since the enum's values are loaded in the order they appear in the code, that constructor is the one for the last value: `East`.

Comment: Well, no, I want the fields position1 and position2 to be on the Main class not fields of the enum. Sure I can add two fields to the enum and in the main method assign the value of those fields to position1 and position2 fields of the main class (position1=d.position1; etc) but I still don't understand why my code gives that output

Comment: @PML All enum constructors are invoked in member declaration order when the enum is first initialized regardless of which member you reference. So before the first iteration of your loop even executes the enum constructor has been invoked 4 times, the last time being by the `East` member. Each invocation overwrites the previous `position1` and `position2` values. That's why all iterations of your loop produce the `East` coordinates.

Comment: @MikeB Ah I see. I was quite sure I didn't understand when the enum costructor was called. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are using `static` fields when your intention is clearly that they be *instance* fields. The values passed to your constructor are all over-written with the last values used.

Remove "static" and move them inside the enum:

```
private enum Direction{
    North(1,1),
    South(-1,-1),
    West(-1,0),
    East(1,0);

    public int position1, position2;

    Direction(int i, int j){
        position1=i;
        position2=j;
    }
}
```

Now refer to the fields of the enum instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args){       

    for(Direction d: Direction.values()){
        System.out.println(d + " has coordinates (" + d.position1 + "," + d.position2 + ")");
    }

}
```

I would make the fields `final` - otherwise they can be changed:

```
public final int position1, position2;
```

Comment: The `position?` fields belong to `Main`, not `Direction`. Whether they are static or not makes no difference here besides the fact that he would have to instantiate `Main` if they weren't.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` isn't your only problem the location of your position fields is incorrect too. Try this:

```
public class Main {
    private enum Direction{
        North(1,1),
        South(-1,-1),
        West(-1,0),
        East(1,0);

        public final int position1;
        public final int position2;

        Direction(int i, int j){
            position1=i;
            position2=j;
        }                        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){       

        for(Direction d: Direction.values()){
            System.out.println(d + " has coordinates (" + d.position1 + "," + d.position2 + ")");
        }

    }  
}
```

Comment: `static isn't your problem` -- it wasn't their _only_ problem, but it was still a problem. If the fields in your code were `static` instead of `final`, there'd be a similar bug.

Comment: @yshavit You are correct, I thought my meaning would be obvious based on context since I made the fields non-static in my example. I'll clarify it for folks that don't catch it.

Comment: The meaning is only useful for people who already know that `static` is wrong here, so it may not have helped the OP (presumably, they wouldn't have used `static` if they knew it was wrong here).